# Django: Prefetch Related multiple reverse relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

class Carnivore(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal)
    testing_params = models.ForeignKey(TestParams, blank=True, null=True)

class TestParams(models.Model):
    params_1 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    params_2 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

class Metrics(models.Model):
    carnivore = models.ForeignKey(Carnivore, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I want to prefetch `carnivore` `animal`, `metrics` for `TestParams` filter objects. So I am doing the following:

```
test_params = TestParams.objects.filter(**filters)

test_params_data = test_params.prefetch_related("carnivore_set", "carnivore_set__animal", "carnivore_set__metrics_set")
```

But I am only getting `carnivore_set` in `_prefetched_objects_cache` parameter when I loop over the `test_params_data` and print each instance's `__dict__`.

So how can I get multi level reverse relationships in `prefetch_related`?

Comment: That makes sense, since the `Prefetch` of the `carnivore_set_animal` for example is a prefetch on prefetching the `carnivore_set`, not the `TestParams`s. This is thus a "nested" prefetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment by @Willem Van Onsem , I found out the answer. This is the solution that I implemented:

```
test_params_data = test_params.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch("carnivore_set", queryset=Carnivore.objects.prefetch_related(
                Prefetch("animal_set", to_attr="animals"),
                Prefetch("metrics_set", to_attr="metrics")), 
            to_attr="carnivores")            
        )
```

This solution worked for me. Please feel free to post any better solution if it exists.